# How to Send API header request through Selenium and get response back

Tags: java, http, selenium, header, testng

I have to automate API through selenium+TestNG (Java). I know its not a good habit to automate APIs using selenium code but still I have got this to do.

Scenario - there is a login API and have to send the email and password and get response back (response code 200). Also can we print the response information also?

Comment: "I know its not a good habit to automate APIs using selenium code" it's not even a question of habit..Selenium is a browser automation tool not an api testing tool.  You can do this using plain java

Comment: Yes Agree that selenium is browser automation tool. Could you please give me java code to do that ?

Comment: Questions of the form "please give me the code" are usually not a good fit here. Can you use an HTTP client plus TestNG to test responses? Maybe give this a go, and then ask a question if you get stuck?

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: Hey, Thanks all for your reply and suggestions. I am newbie in selenium and java so do not have much knowledge about that. I have posted this questions after researching so much. Now somehow I could achieved what i wanted to implement. thanks all for your support.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on java you can use JAVA socket libraries for the same:

Here are the sample code for POST API:

```
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    // add request header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    String urlParameters = "j_username=" + user + "&j_password=" + pass
            + "";

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
```

For GET API:

```
obj = new URL(url);
    obj.openConnection();
    con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());

    // add request header
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8l");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
    con.setRequestProperty(
            "Cookie",
            "BIGipServerPRODCAN-Default=423078080.2087.0000; __utma=44365112.1659763098.1418886605.1427784911.1441869730.4; __utmc=44365112; __utmz=44365112.1427784911.3.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); JSESSIONID="
                    + cookieValue);

    responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    File file = new File(prop.getFilePath() + "//XMLs//" + fileName
            + ".xml");
    file.delete();
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(prop.getFilePath() + "//XMLs//"
            + fileName + ".xml", true);

    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

        out.write(inputLine.toString());
        out.newLine();

        response.append(inputLine);
    }

    in.close();
    out.close();`
```